# Google action don't stop audio with cancel intent

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have a bug from a few days: after opening the dialog in a smartspeaker (in a real device, not in a simulator by dialogflow), and after asking to listen to an audio (like a podcast), if I decide to exit the dialog it works and close the conversation, but after that the audio continues to play.

The "cancel" intent to exit from the conversation is correct, according to the google guideline, but I note that event ["*actions_intent_CANCEL*"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ti42C.png) doesn't exist anymore. I image it's a problem for many skill. Is there a solution for this problem? Does it depend for an update or other?

Comment: Is not clear what you are trying to accomplish, when you said "asking to listen to an audio" you are referring that you want the device to play a podcast? If this is correct, I think this is working as intended, because you are closing the conversation not stop the audio.

Either way, could you  please share where you are not seeing the "actions_intent_CANCEL" anymore? A a code snippet and which guide you are following.

Comment: Exactly. I ask to play a podcast and after that to close my dialog with smart speaker, without stopping the podcast before. Until some week ago there wasn't problems, but now the audio not stopping. Of course I must command to stop the audio, but I try to check every case becouse the users are not accurate with the commanda. I think that the skill moust to stop the audio before to close the dialog eith the user.
I added a image link in the original post with the code where I not seeing the actions_intent_CANCEL anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the "actions_intent_CANCEL" is no longer available and belongs to the [Legacy SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/conversation-exits#dialogflow), and as the documentation states you would need to use the new version, however, is not clear what is the equivalent event. What I would recommend is to contact their [Support team](https://support.google.com/actions-console/contact/support), so they can provide you with more insights.

In addition, I would recommend to check the documentation for [Media Responses](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/prompts-media).

Comment: I will write to the support. I know how Media Responses do, but it's normal to think that users ask to exit from the dialog without stopped the podcast before.

Comment: So... the support team write me that it's possibile that there are some issues with difference device, operating system, etc... but not writes nothing about "actions_intent_CANCEL" event or my main problem. I don't resolving nothing, my audio keeping play when I close the dialog.
I can't pretend the user ask to stopping podcast audio before say good by (exit) from the dialog with google smartspeaker.